# Linking two related lists of different lengths in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of ints:
eg

```
a = [ 008, 016, 024... ]

b = [001, 002, 002, 003... 012, 016]
```

List a increments consistently by 8 while list b is more random (eg sometimes two recorded ints).

Essentially what i want to do is produce a dict linking these two such that a[i] = b[i] <= a[i+1] it is appended to such?

So i would get from b:

```
c = [ 008, 008, 008, 008 ... 016, 016]
```

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. You want to create a `dict` with constraints on `a` and `b`, but you list `c` as an example solution, which is a list. Could you restate the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to build a list containing the index in `b` of each value in `a`.  Or something equivalent to it.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
>>> a = [ 8, 16, 24, 32 ]
>>> b = [1, 2, 2, 3, 12, 16]
>>> [a[0] if a[0] < x and [a.pop(0)] else a[0] for x in b ]
[8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16]
```

Using [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(a)
>>> [d[0] if d[0] < x and [d.popleft()] else d[0] for x in b ]
[8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16]
```

A much read-able version:

```
>>> it = iter(a)
>>> prev = next(it)
>>> result = []
for x in b:
    if x <= prev:
        result.append(prev)
    else:
        prev = next(it)
        result.append(prev)
...         
>>> result
[8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16]
```

Comment: This will modify `a` won't it?

Comment: Well, he never said he wanted to keep `a` `:-)`

Comment: @2rs2ts yes, but we can keep a copy of `a`. That's not the problem here. :)

Comment: Of course. Just wanted to make sure that OP knew the side effects.

Comment: @2rs2ts Yes. Also `pop(0)` is usually something you don't want to do with a list. To avoid both these problems you can do `a = deque(a)` and use `popleft()`.

Comment: Brilliant, i'll look into deques as well. I tried doing a low-level approach were i was dividing each element by 8 and then rounding to produce a rounded version of a... and then multiplying back by 8... But this is much more elegant

Answer (score 0):

As a generator:

```
def make_c(a, b):
    a_idx = 0
    for elt in b:
        # while loop can be replaced with "if"
        # as long as jumps in b never skip elements in a
        while elt > a[a_idx]: 
            a_idx += 1
        yield a[a_idx]
```